# how to generate 4 MHz clock from 2 MHz clock in FPGA

Tags: fpga

I need to generate 4 Mhz clock from 2 MHz clock . I checked clocking wizard/MMCM/PLL , but there input clock range start from 10 MHz.

I had read about using rising and falling edge detectors but they fail to give 50% duty cycle.

can DDS(direct digital synthesizer ) convert 2MHz clock frequency into 4MHz frequency??

what are the other methods to do that??

Regards
Ankit

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then [edit] you question and provide more information about the FPGA you plan to use, and the tool chain for it. Do this by [edit]ing your question, don't add it in a comment, please.

Comment: If the 4MHz is to be driven outside FPGA, ODDR can be used. But this clock can't be used inside FPGA.

Comment: Here's someone that says they were able to do it: https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Other-FPGA-Architecture/Locking-the-PLL-on-lower-freqency-Resetting-the-PLL-counters/m-p/852667

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ That aside, if it's your FPGA, you'd likely be better off going to opposite direction--it'll be more accurate.